# Retrieve or set LESS variable from JavaScript?

Tags: css, less

While testing my web app, I'd like to be able to set the value of one of my LESS @variables  using a simple dropdown. (To change the color scheme altogether).

I guess after setting the value, LESS has to reload/recompile the .less files with the new value?

Is there any simple way of accomplishing this? (I'm not running node.js)

The basic example would be something like:

```
styles.less
@base-color = `window.baseColor()`
```

Comment: What do you mean, you don't run node.js? Is your LESS-file compiled into CSS on the server-side?

Comment: No, I'm just including it like this: <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less"> 
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're doing it in a bit too complicated way ;)

Here's what I propose:

1. Set a class on your body tag:

   ```
   <body class='theme_default'></body>
   ```
2. In your .less file define your themes:

   ```
   body.theme_default { base_color: #fff; }
   body.theme_gray    { base_color: #ccc; }
   etc..
   ```
3. Using jQuery (or just plain JS) change the class of the body tag upon dropdown state change.

That's how I'd do it (and replace the dropdown with some nice widget ;)
Cheers

Comment: Ahh, that sounds much more reasonable :)