# Share variable between less and coffeescript?

Tags: java, javascript, css, coffeescript, playframework-2.0

Is it possible to **share** variables between `Less`(CSS) and `CoffeScript`(JavaScript) in Play.

Less:

```
@width: 600px;
@height: 800px;

.right {
  width: @width;
  height: @height;
}
```

CoffeScript:

```
width = 600
height = 800

stage = new Kinetic.Stage(
  container: 'mainCanvas'
  width: width
  height: height
)
```

I find it highly inconvenient to have to repeat myself in both files.

Naturally I would like to be able to define the width and the height at a higher abstraction layer.

Of course any technique that is more general and may be applied to any framework is also appreciated.

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296906/retrieve-or-set-less-variable-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you simply try to set the css-class via jquery?

```
stage = new Kinetic.Stage
    container: 'mainCanvas'
    width: 0
    height: 0

mc = $("#mainCanvas")
#assuming that mainCanvas is the element you want to style
mc.addClass "right"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion +1 , I can see it working for styling issues however this is not only for appearance (browser rendition) but also for internal Java Script calculations. For example the "stage" wouldn't update it's internal Java Script variables on an Class change (Add, Remove)

Comment: However you have given me an approach to work with I'm pondering the though of creating a hidden dummy element and parse the variables from css in Java Script and set them to an config object in Java Script which I then later could use as parameters for the "Stage" constructor.

Comment: @Farmor Perfect! that was my initial thought ;-)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way as far as I'm concerned.

Maybe you can define a class in CSS and adjust the width and height just from style.

Answer (score 0):

[Rosetta](https://npmjs.org/package/rosetta) is what you are looking for.

---

From npm page...

Example
Imagine you want to want to create a shared variable:

```
$thumbnailSize = 250px
```

Rosetta allows you to use this variable in both your Javascript:

```
var rosetta = require('./rosetta');
console.log('Thumbnail size is:', rosetta.thumbnailSize.val);
```

...and your CSS (in this case, a Stylus file):

```
@import rosetta
.thumb { 
  width: $thumbnailSize
  height: $thumbnailSize
}
```

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.